# Implementing a Opaque handle in java

Tags: java, handle

I want to implement an opaque handle in java.

i.e. when the user calls Create on my Factory kind of class, I create an object of the class, but don't return the object itself but an int representing the instance of the class. I will have a `HashMap` which will store the int as the key and the object as value.
Every other method of the class will take an int as one parameter & it will retrieve the object from the `HashMap` and do the required operation on the corresponding object.
There will be a remove method which will remove it from the `HashMap` and allow it to be garbage collected.

I was wondering if there is any existing class/data structure which will avoid me having to implement the handle part of the code?

I don't think I can use `hashCode` or `identityHashCode` as the unique identifier because they aren't guaranteed to be unique.

If I implement a running counter myself, I will have to handle issues like thread safety while creating the Unique Id, reusing of ids when I remove the object from the `hashMap` etc. So I was wondering if there is any existing class which can help with this.

Comment: Is it necessary that the handle is an `int`? You could maintain type safety if you used some kind of handle class instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes - it needs to be an int :-(

Comment: May I ask why the handle must be an int ? Another question is how many objects will you need at one time in your map, and how long lived are those objects ? I ask because you seem to be be afraid of the AtomicInteger solution...

Comment: @AtomicInteger makes one of my issues simpler - the synchronization one. I have no problems using it. Doesn't solve the 'reclaiming removed handles issue'. Total number of objects at any time would peak at probably 5000-10000. Objects will live for an hour or so at maximum. However, I don't want stuff to break down the above assumptions are crossed. Instead of saying 'Handle has to be int', I should have probably said 'Handle cannot be a class object' - it has to be a basic type (int, long etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do simple calculations. You said you would have max 10000 objects, max 1 hour livetime. Let assume more tough conditions - 10000 objects per 1 minute. The 32 bit integer will be enough for about 1 year. Moreover even if the integer overflows, it will start from zero again, reusing integers used 1 year ago. As I see it is more than enough. So, just use AtomicInteger it works very fast and more than enough for your requirements.

If still you have doubts, you could have a more resilient solution - when a new handle is generated, check first if the HashMap has this key already (it is very fast operation), if it does have, just pick the next integer. It is similar to https://superuser.com/questions/135007/how-are-pids-generated in operation systems.

Comment: `The 32 bit integer will be enough for about 1 year.` Since int is signed, it will last only for 149 days and not 1 year. But you do make a good point. And I think a signed long will last for more than my life time I think.

Comment: @user93353 Negatives are good numbers too :) So, you could use a negative integer as a handler too I believe. And yes... `long` will last nearly the same as the age of the Universe.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep my own counter. Use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) if you're worried about thread safety.

And I wouldn't try to re-use ids: that will make debugging and logging very difficult.
You aren't likely to run out of Integers.

Comment: It's going to be a very long running application - so I will eventually run out of integers. That's one of the reason I was wondering if there is any existing implementation which will take care of reclaiming ids where the object itself has been garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Take a long value as id. You will never run out of longs. re using an int introduces higher complexity and a slow down.
writing an get() set() and increment() using syncronized (or a private lock object) is simple. Otherwise use `AtomicLong` with `incrementAndGet()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use basic OO design which returns an encapsulated object - it's simple, powerful and well-known.

Don't return an int from the factory and pass it to the factory methods.  Instead, declare a specific class for the newly created object (abstract data type) and return an instance of this ADT class.  Move the methods that operate on your object from the factory to the ADT class.

E.g.

```
// file Widget.java
package com.company.widgets;

public class Widget {
    String widgetName;
    String widgetType;
    int widgetCode;

    // By making the constructor "protected", can stop arbitrary classes from 
    // constructing and ensure on the WidgetFactory can construct
    protected Widget(String widgetName,
                    String widgetType,
                    int widgetCode) {
         this.widgetName = widgetName;
         this.widgetType = widgetType;
         this.widgetCode = widgetCode;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
         ...
    }

    public int hashcode() {
         ...
    }

    public void widgetOperation1(String fred) {
        ...
    }

    public String widgetOperation2(int barney ) {
        ...
    }
}

//========================================================

// file WidgetFactory.java
package com.company.widgets;

public class WidgetFactory {
    // Member attributes as needed. E.g. static Set of created Widget objects
    private static Set<Widget> widgetSet;
    static { widgetSet = new HashSet() }

    // 
    public static Widget createNewWidget() {
        Widget widget = new Widget();
        widgetSet.add(widget);
        return widget;
    }

    public static removeWidget(Widget widget) {
        widgetSet.remove(Widget)
    }
}
```

Note that 1000 objects is not many, so this solution will be performant.  If you really need to optimise every microsecond of performance, you have the option to make the factory smarter, so that Widgets are not deleted, but are recycled - e.g. you could have two Sets, widgetsInUseSet and widgetsRecycledSet.

Comment: As I have said multiple times on this page - I know it's trivial to implement this thing with an object instead of an int. But unfortunately there are reasons I cannot - and it's not because of performance reasons.

Comment: What are the reasons?  I'm genuinely interested to know.  I've read thoroughly and you haven't given them.